# Alternative for OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor that depends on a deprecated class

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

*Disclaimer: I honestly tried to google/github this, scanned through the [OAuth2 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide), but couldn't find an answer to this, so here we go.*

[org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.client.feign.OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/blob/master/spring-cloud-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/security/oauth2/client/feign/OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor.java) from spring-cloud-security project acquires OAuth2 token and sets it to a Feign's RequestTemplate transparently to a client's invoker.
However, it relies on a deprecated [OAuth2ClientContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2ClientContext.java) class, which refers to an aforementioned migration guide, which still says that

> For other flows, an OAuth2ClientContext instance needs to be
>   constructed and exposed.

So would be great to know several things:
 1. Is it really deprecated, or it's just that its usage should change (at least in certain cases)?
 2. If former - what's the correct alternative?
 3. Are there any plans to migrate `OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor` from using the deprecated classes?

Answer (score 2):

The classes **OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor**  and  **OAuth2ClientContext** has changed in the latest versions. It's changed to *@Deprecated* now. It already has an open [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/417) linked to it. Lets understand it one by one.

1. OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor : Previously it used to be a part of s*pring-cloud-security*. You can now find it in the below link  
   [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign)
   Exact class is in this link [OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/main/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/security/OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor.java). This project is still a work in progress.
2. OAuth2ClientContext : If we look carefully in the javadoc present in
   the class it says:

   @deprecated See the [OAuth
   2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) for Spring Security 5.    The migration Guide mentioned in the link states that

   > This document contains guidance for moving OAuth 2.0 Clients and
   > Resource Servers from Spring Security OAuth 2.x to Spring Security
   > 5.2.x. Since Spring Security doesn’t provide Authorization Server support, migrating a Spring Security OAuth Authorization Server is
   > out
   > of scope for this document.

   The latest changes are present in spring-security. In
   **spring-security** 5.3.x information related to OAuth2 client  can be found in the this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.3.x/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client) . [OAuth2AuthorizedClient.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.3.x/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClient.java)

   You will get more details if you refer to the information
   provided in the Migration Guide.

   In future it will be a part of [Spring Authorization
   Server](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server).
    Github : [spring-authorization-server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization)  which
   under development. A lot of OAuth2 related stuff is present. e.g.
   [OAuth2Authorization.java](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/OAuth2Authorization.java)  which will used to getAccessToken,
   RefreshToken etc.

Some more information from Stackoverflow about the alternatives which might help. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66195349/how-to-provide-an-oauth2-token-to-a-feign-client-using-spring-security-for-the-c)